# maintaining state between two components in a js package

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I want to create a React package that will have two components, one to preload assets, and another to play/use those assets. Usage would look like this:

```
// Usage

import { PreloaderComponent, NotificationComponent } from 'module';

const Consumer: React.FC = () => {
    render (
        <>
            <PreloaderComponent />
            ...
            { condition && <NotificationComponent />}
        </>
    )
}
```

I believe I'll need to persist state in my package... something like

```
// package

const assetStore = () => {
    const path = 'path.mp3';
    const loadedAsset;

    const preload = () => {
        loadedAsset = new Asset(path);
    }

    const getAsset = () => {
        // check if preloaded
        // if not, load
        return loadedAsset;
    }

    return {
        preload,
        getAsset
    };
}

const PreloaderComponent: null = () => {
    const store = assetStore();
    assetStore.preload();

    return null;
}

const NotificationComponent: React.FC = () => {
    // if (already instantiated)
    // get access to previously instantiated store
    const assetObject = assetStore.getAsset();

    assetObject.play()

    render (
        <div> // or whatever
    )

}

export {
    PreloaderComponent,
    NotificationComponent
};
```

But the above code won't work, since the NotificationComponent doesn't have access to the previously instantiated store. I considered a factory pattern but then you'd need to instantiate that factory somewhere.

How would you preload the assets by calling one component, then use those assets in another? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A context might be the way to go. The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) describe when to use contexts like this:

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components

So an example would be an `AssetContext` with a `useContext`-hook to simplify things:

```
import React, { useCallback, useContext, useState } from "react";

const AssetContext = React.createContext();

const AssetProvider = (props) => {
  const [assets, setAssets] = useState([]);

  const value = {
    assets,
    addAsset: (asset) => {
      setAssets([...assets, asset]);
    },
    clear: () => setAssets([])
  };

  return <AssetContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />;
};

const useAssets = () => useContext(AssetContext)
```

You can use the data provided by the context with `useAssets()`:

```
const Preloader = () => {
  const {addAsset} = useAssets();


  useCallback(() => {
    addAsset({play: () => console.log('sth')})
  })

  return <div>
    {/* */}
    </div>
}

const Notifier = () => {
  const {assets} = useAssets();

  // example usage based on your code
  const [firstAsset] = assets

  if(firstAsset) {
    firstAsset.play();
  }

  return <div>
    {/* */}
    </div>
}
```

Don't forget to encapuslate those components within the `AssetProvider`. It's not required to put them directly as the children of the provider but somewhere bellow it.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <AssetProvider>
      <Preloader />
      <Notifier />
    </AssetProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks this is helpful. is there a way to do it without encapsulating in a provider component? If possible I'd like to not need that requirement in using the package.

Comment: no. Even if you use something else like Redux, some sort of Provider is required. An alternative way would be to use events, but I don't think that's a simple, clean solution.